# CSS overflow:auto on inline-block with non-fixed width issue in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, scrollbar, overflow

The problem is in Chrome and Firefox.

Scroll container is an inline-block with non-fixed `width` and `max-height` with `overflow:auto`.

When the inner `.content` div has `padding`, scrollbar apears over the right padding area. However, when I set `overflow-y:scroll`, the scrollbar apears in the correct place and the width of the `.scroll` div is increased.

See reproduction in [JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/cj9gxbm8/).

How to fix it?

```
body {
    background: #fff;
}
.scroll {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #f99;
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
}
.content {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

In Opera 12 and IE 9+ all OK

https://i.gyazo.com/6c84537d6c0dc1422981342785893277.png

Comment: It seems that since this post Chrome has fixed this behavior (at least, it doesn't reproduce in Chrome 61/Win 10), but Firefox 56/Win 10 still has this weirdness:(. I'm also looking for a pure CSS solution for this...

Comment: Found out that it's a known Firefox bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1335265